# Python 3.10/3.11 changes on os.path.join()

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I switched from Python 3.9 to 3.11 and noticed a change in this case:

Python 3.11:

```
import os
os.path.join(r"\\", "foo")
'\\\\\\foo'
```

Python 3.9:

```
import os
os.path.join(r"\\", "foo")
'\\\\foo'
```

There seems to be an additional backslash in Pythons 3.11 output, what change did cause this (changelog)?

Comment: Did you read the "what's new in Python 3.x" announcements?

Comment: did not find any change relevant to it, i tried to find it!